Create mutlicolumns and multirows simultaneously
I want to create several columns and rows simultaneously.
I found different approaches (\Block or nested \multicolumn in \multirow) but they did not work for me. (Especially because the examples did not have several rows before the merges cells.)
This is the mwe and what I want in a picture below.
 \documentclass{scrbook}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{booktabs} 
    \usepackage{tabularx, ragged2e} 
    \usepackage[longtable]{multirow} 
    \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
    
    \begin{document}
        
    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{table}[H]
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \begin{tabularx}{\paperwidth}{XXXXXXXXXX}
                \toprule[1.5pt] 
                && \multicolumn{3}{c}{Hello}&&\multicolumn{3}{c}{World}&\\
                \cmidrule{3-5}  \cmidrule{7-9}  
                A & B & C & D & E &  & F & G & H & I \\
                \midrule
                \multirow[c]{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{items 1\\and 2}} 
                & item 1     & 0.01  & 0.02  & 0.015  & & 693329 &  6786784 &  862556 & Bla \\
                & item 2     & 0.002 & 0.02  & 0.011  & & 693329 &  7356548 &  736283 & Bla \\
                \multirow[c]{5}{*}{Items 3-6} 
                & item 3    &&&&&&&&\\
                & item 4    &&&&&&&&\\
                & item 5    &&&&&&&&\\  
                & item 6    &&&&&&&&\\
                \bottomrule 
            \end{tabularx}
        \end{threeparttable}
        \end{table}
    \end{landscape}
    
    \end{document}



You can simply remove the right most & delimieters, just leaving the \.  Now putting the text "Merge cells" in the center might be a bit of a challenge.

I am so sorry, I do not understand your approach?

In your code, I have loaded nicematrix, replaced {tabularx} by {NiceTabularX} and put a command \Block{*-*}{Merge Cells}. That does the job...
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{tabularx, ragged2e} 
\usepackage[longtable]{multirow} 
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[H]

\begin{NiceTabularX}{\linewidth}{XXXXXXXXXX}
    \toprule[1.5pt] 
    && \multicolumn{3}{c}{Hello}&&\multicolumn{3}{c}{World}&\\
    \cmidrule{3-5}  \cmidrule{7-9}  
    A & B & C & D & E &  & F & G & H & I \\
    \midrule
    \multirow[c]{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{items 1\\and 2}} 
    & item 1     & 0.01  & 0.02  & 0.015  & & 693329 &  6786784 &  862556 & Bla \\
    & item 2     & 0.002 & 0.02  & 0.011  & & 693329 &  7356548 &  736283 & Bla \\
    \multirow[c]{4}{*}{Items 3-6} 
    & item 3    &\Block{*-*}{Merge Cells}\\
    & item 4    \\
    & item 5    \\  
    & item 6    \\
    \bottomrule 
\end{NiceTabularX}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}


However, in "pure" nicematrix (if I can say...), here is the standard coding:
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{10}{X}}
    \toprule[1.5pt] 
    && \Block{1-3}{Hello} &&&& \Block{1-3}{World} \\
    \cmidrule{3-5}  \cmidrule{7-9}  
    A & B & C & D & E &  & F & G & H & I \\
    \midrule
    \Block[t,l]{2-1}{items 1\\and 2}
    & item 1     & 0.01  & 0.02  & 0.015  & & 693329 &  6786784 &  862556 & Bla \\
    & item 2     & 0.002 & 0.02  & 0.011  & & 693329 &  7356548 &  736283 & Bla \\
    \Block{4-1}{Items 3-6} 
    & item 3    &\Block{*-*}{Merge Cells}\\
    & item 4    \\
    & item 5    \\  
    & item 6    \\
    \bottomrule 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}

The output is the same.

No need of manual adjustment with tabularray:
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
  \begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tblr}{
      width=\linewidth,
      colspec={*{10}{X}},
      row{3}={belowsep=0pt},
      row{4-Y}={rowsep=0pt},
      row{Z}={abovesep=0pt},
      }
      \toprule[1.5pt] 
      && \SetCell[c=3]{c} Hello&&&&\SetCell[c=3]{c} World&&\\
      \cmidrule{3-5}  \cmidrule{7-9}  
      A & B & C & D & E &  & F & G & H & I \\
      \midrule
      \SetCell[r=2]{l} {items 1\\and 2} & item 1     & 0.01  & 0.02  & 0.015  & & 693329 &  6786784 &  862556 & Bla \\
      & item 2     & 0.002 & 0.02  & 0.011  & & 693329 &  7356548 &  736283 & Bla \\
      \SetCell[r=4]{l} Items 3-6 & item 3 &\SetCell[c=8,r=4]{c} Merge Cells&&&&&&&\\
      & item 4    \\
      & item 5    \\  
      & item 6    \\
      \bottomrule 
    \end{tblr}
  \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}



You can always replace \multirow with \raisebox
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{tabularx, ragged2e} 
\usepackage[longtable]{multirow} 
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[H]
    %\begin{threeparttable}% not used
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXXXXXXXX}
            \toprule[1.5pt] 
            && \multicolumn{3}{c}{Hello}&&\multicolumn{3}{c}{World}&\\
            \cmidrule{3-5}  \cmidrule{7-9}  
            A & B & C & D & E &  & F & G & H & I \\
            \midrule
            \multirow[c]{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{items 1\\and 2}} 
            & item 1     & 0.01  & 0.02  & 0.015  & & 693329 &  6786784 &  862556 & Bla \\
            & item 2     & 0.002 & 0.02  & 0.011  & & 693329 &  7356548 &  736283 & Bla \\
            \multirow[c]{4}{*}{Items 3-6} 
            & item 3    &\multicolumn{8}{c}{\raisebox{-1.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{Merge Cells}}\\
            & item 4    \\
            & item 5    \\  
            & item 6    \\
            \bottomrule 
        \end{tabularx}
    %\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}


Thanks - this worked out. Although the double backslashes appear marked red, it works.

Your editor is reminding you that you are (deliberately) missing a few columns.
